# React newbie: Provider not updating upon reducer execution

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I've been using React for a week now, and have hit a roadblock when implementing providers. I'm using `connect`, `mapStateToProps` and `mapDispatchToProps` to simplify a previously functioning app. I have a `CommentsContainer` component linked to a `Comments` component, which maps out child `Comment` components. The first action I've implemented is `onDeleteClick` on the `Comment` component's `onClick` event. I figured it'd be straightforward, but I can't get the page to rerender with updated state (aka remove the deleted `Comment` component) after the event fires. Chrome inspector confirms that:

- The reducer case is firing
- The deleted Comment is being deleted from state

But state simply isn't updating. I thought I had a solid grasp of how state triggered, but I guess I'm missing something. Relevant code below, any ideas greatly appreciated.

**App.js (main access point)**

```
import React from 'react';
import CommentsContainer from './components/CommentsContainer';
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import commentsReducer from './reducers/CommentsReducer';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';

const store = createStore(commentsReducer);
const rootEl = document.getElementById('root');

const render = () => ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}><CommentsContainer /></Provider>, rootEl
)
```

**CommentsContainer.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import Comments from './Comments';
import { removeComment } from '../actions/CommentsAction';

const mapStateToProps = state => {
  return {
    comments: state
  }
}

const mapDispatchToProps = dispatch => {
  return  {
    onDeleteClick: id => {
      dispatch(removeComment(id))
    }
  }
}

const CommentsContainer = connect(
  mapStateToProps,
  mapDispatchToProps
)(Comments);

export default CommentsContainer;
```

**Comments.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import Comment from './Comment';

const Comments = ({ comments, onDeleteClick }) => (
  <div className='comments'>{comments.map((comment) => (<Comment key={comment.id} comment={comment} onDeleteClick={onDeleteClick} />))}
  </div>
)

export default Comments;
```

**Comment.js**

```
import React from 'react';

const Comment  = ({ comment, onDeleteClick}) => (
  <div className='comment'>
    <div className='comment-user'>{comment.user}</div>
    <div className='comment-content'>{comment.content}</div>
    <div className='delete-comment' onClick={(e) => { onDeleteClick(comment)}}>Delete</div>
  </div>
)

export default Comment;
```

**CommentsReducer.js**

```
import * as constants from '../Constants';

const CommentsReducer = (state=[
  {id: '123', user: 'Test Reducer User', content: 'Test Content'},
  {id: '456', user:  'Other Reducer User', content: 'Other Content'}
], action) => {

  let comments;

  switch(action.type) {
    case constants.REMOVE_COMMENT:
      comments = state;
      for (let i = comments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (comments[i].id == action.comment.id) {
          comments.splice(i,1);
          break;
        }
      }
      break;
    default:
      comments = state;
  }

  return comments;
}

export default CommentsReducer;
```

**CommentsAction.src**

```
import * as constants from '../Constants';

export const removeComment = comment => {
  return {
    type: constants.REMOVE_COMMENT,
    comment
  }
}
```

**Constants.js**

```
export const REMOVE_COMMENT = 'REMOVE_COMMENT';
```

**Index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Demo React App</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="root"></div>
    <div id='commentForm'></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Any errors in console? You are mutating state - `comments = state`. get rid of it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using Redux, make sure you **never** mutate the state. Always return a new state ( if there is a state change ). In that view, your reducer is essentially mutating the state. Use functions like `.slice()`, `.filter()` or object spread operator to create new state. See https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/ImmutableUpdatePatterns.html for more details.

Your reducer should be:

```
const CommentsReducer = (state=[
  {id: '123', user: 'Test Reducer User', content: 'Test Content'},
  {id: '456', user:  'Other Reducer User', content: 'Other Content'}
], action) => {

  let comments;

  switch(action.type) {
    case constants.REMOVE_COMMENT:
      comments = [...state];        // use of object spread operator. You can also do comments = state.slice() or use filter() function
      for (let i = comments.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
        if (comments[i].id == action.comment.id) {
          comments.splice(i,1);
          break;
        }
      }
      break;
    default:
      comments = state;
  }

  return comments;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Avoid mutating state that is array/object directly in React.

Instead of `comments.splice(index, 1)`, use `return comments.filter(comment => comment.id !== removeId)` in reducer.

Immutability in React-Redux app is fairly important, many internal performance improvement tricks (e.g, shouldComponentUpdate) rely on it.

Answer (score 1):

One of the core principals behind Redux (the state store you've decided to use)
is immutibility.

Which means you get the current state inside your CommentsReducer and are supposed to return a new state (as in a completely new javascript object)

Your reducer **mutates** the current state instead of returning a completely new object which contains the comments with a reduced comment.

Something like this would help:
Please note I am assuming your state is an object and NOT an array as you used.
That way it's much easier to use Object.assign() to easily create a brand new object from scratch every time you want to change the state.

```
  case constants.REMOVE_COMMENT:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      comments: state.comments.filter(c => c.id !== action.comment.id)
    });
```

Please note that this is the entire point behind Redux's ability to notice your application state has changed (It compares the object pointers of the previous state and the new state returned by your reducer)

If the object is the same instance , Redux deduces that the state hasn't changed which is exactly what happend in your example.

Hope this helps!